# VS Code не видит виртуального окружения

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

Я использую Coockiecutter для быстрого создания проекта из шаблона, при создании проекта создается виртуальное окружение проекта:

```
import subprocess


def venv():

    bashCommand = "python3 -m virtualenv ../{{cookiecutter.repo_name}}/venv"
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()

    if error:
        print(error)

venv()
```

В итоге получается следующая структура папок

```
repo_name/                                  # Наименование репозитория указанного при формирование стрктуры
    ├── code/                               # Вспомогательные скрипты
    ├── data/                               # Данные получаемые при отработке скрипта
    ├── input/                              # Данные необходимые для выполнения скрипта
    ├── notebook/                           # Jupyter Notebookk скрипты
         ├── *.ipynb                        
    ├── project/                            # Информация о проекте
    ├── venv/                               # Виртуальное окружение
```

Окружение активируется, и ставятся либы, соответственно глобально их не видно. Но что бы работать с ними , необходимо переключить интерпретаторы VS Code[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но возникает проблема что VS Code не видит виртуального окружения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если указывать путь напрямую до папки venv то
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но толку от этого мало

Хотя если вынести отдельно *.ipynb и папку venv то он сразу видит виртуальное окружение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может ли VS Code не видит его из за .gitignore ?
Дело в том что в самой папке venv есть .gitignore с условием *
Соответственно (и это прпаильно) папка не индексируется

Comment: `.gitignore` отвечает за работу с репозиторием, никакого отношения к проектным настройкам а тем более виртуальному окружению он не имеет, вообще vscode работает с папками, поэтому не удивительно что при папке он видит окружение, vscode создает еще дополнительный скрытый файл для своих настроек поэтому дирректории приветсвуются, есть разница открыть файл или папку, открывая файл не надейтесь увидить что-то из окружения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовал все это через conda, оказалось на много удобней и меньше телодвижений. После установки conda VS code прекрасно видит окружение